# How to add customized toolbar in front of first component on top codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I try to put other toolbar instead of the default toolbar, but when I do it the customized toolbar is on front of the first component above.

[image]

```
    Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(false);
    Button cabeza = new Button(" First Button");
    cabeza.setUIID("HeadMes");
    Command[] comando = {new Command("OK")};

    TextArea subcabeza = new TextArea("Header 1");
    subcabeza.setEditable(false);
    subcabeza.setFocusable(false);
    subcabeza.setUIID("LabelDiaNormal");
    subcabeza.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
    subcabeza.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xffffff);
    subcabeza.getAllStyles().setAlignment(RIGHT);
    subcabeza.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0x000000);

    Button cabeza2 = new Button(" Second Button");
    cabeza2.setUIID("HeadMes");

    Container titulos = BoxLayout.encloseY(cabeza,subcabeza,cabeza2);

    Form hi = new Form("Diseño Beta",new BorderLayout());

    Toolbar tb = new Toolbar(true);
    hi.setToolbar(tb);
    tb.setUIID("BetaTB");        
    tb.setTitle("Diseño_Beta");

    hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH,titulos);        

    hi.show();
    hi.setAllowEnableLayoutOnPaint(true);
```

Now it seems with the default toolbar

[image]

```
    Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);
    Button cabeza = new Button(" First Button");
    cabeza.setUIID("HeadMes");
    Command[] comando = {new Command("OK")};

    TextArea subcabeza = new TextArea("Header 1");
    subcabeza.setEditable(false);
    subcabeza.setFocusable(false);
    subcabeza.setUIID("LabelDiaNormal");
    subcabeza.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
    subcabeza.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xffffff);
    subcabeza.getAllStyles().setAlignment(RIGHT);
    subcabeza.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0x000000);

    Button cabeza2 = new Button(" Second Button");
    cabeza2.setUIID("HeadMes");

    Container titulos = BoxLayout.encloseY(cabeza,subcabeza,cabeza2);

    Form hi = new Form("Diseño Beta",new BorderLayout());

    hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH,titulos);        

    hi.show();
    hi.setAllowEnableLayoutOnPaint(true);
```

It appears good in form, but I don't know how to change all the style on the title bar, so that's why I decided to customized my own toolbar.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution, and it was too easy. Just changed this line, and set to false.

```
Toolbar tb = new Toolbar(false);
```

Now the toolbar is working good.